# I want a simple text printed UNDER my display in this Python hangman code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want the text "Congrats, You have chosen the right letter!" to appear UNDER my display word in the terminal in this hangman code every time the user guesses the right word for the first time only.

How it is now:

```
[ w _ r _ r _ d ]
```

How I want it to be:

```
[ w _ r _ r _ d ]
"Congrats, You have chosen the right letter!"
```

Challenge:

Right now, every time the user inputs a letter they did previously, the text "You have already chosen this letter" will appear.

I want to add a congratulating text UNDER the display every time the user has a correct input *for the first time*. The congratulating text should only appear once when a correct letter is chosen for the first time. If the letter is chosen another time, the text "You have already chosen this letter" should appear with NO congratulations.

How it should be when the user inputs a correct letter in the hangman for the first time:

```
[ w _ r _ r _ d ]
"Congrats, You have chosen the right letter!"
```

How it should be when the user chooses the same input again:

```
[ w _ r _ r _ d ]
"You have already chosen this letter"
```

How can I have both texts when an input is correct, but have the congratulating text ONLY when the correct letter is chosen for the first time, and of course, the text should be under the hangman display word, not above.

I tried placing the print function below the display of the word, but it gets stuck there forever!

I also tried adding the congratulating text after a user has a correct input, but as you can imagine, it will be printed every time the user guesses the correct letter, when I only want the text to appear only when they guess it right the first time, and a "You have already chosen that letter" text after they repeat it.

Full Code:

```
import random
from replit import clear
from hangman_art import logo, stages
print(logo)
print("\nWelcome to Lucid's Hangman!")

from hangman_words import word_list

choice = random.choice(word_list)
print(choice)

lives = 6
running = True

display = []
for letter in choice:
display += "_"

while running:

  guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
  clear()
  if guess in display:
    print("You have already chosen that letter")

  for position in range(len(choice)):
    letter = choice[position]
    if letter == guess:
      display[position] = letter
  print(display)

  if guess not in display:
    lives -= 1
    print("You have chosen a wrong letter. You lose a life")
    if lives == 0:
      running = False
      print("You lose!")
  if "_" not in display:
    running = False
    print("You have won!")

  print(stages[lives])
```

Comment: Start with fixing code indentation? You have at least one indentation error at line `"display += "_"`. On the side, also refrain from assigning `display`as a variable since it it already a Python function.

Answer (score 0):

To show the word before telling them they already chose a letter, print `display` when you detect that, and then restart the loop so you skip the rest of the checks.

```
  if guess in display:
    print(display)
    print("You have already chosen that letter")
    continue
```

To print the message telling them they got a correct letter, add an `else` clause to the next `if`.

```
  if guess not in display:
    lives -= 1
    print("You have chosen a wrong letter. You lose a life")
    if lives == 0:
      running = False
      print("You lose!")
  else:
    print("Congrats, You have chosen the right letter!")
```